# Deleting partial data from a field in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I am trying to remove a specific set of data from a MySQL database field, however I am not sure what the best statement would be for this.   For example, if I have a data in a field such as...

*The use of a secondary password will allow you to gain access to your account from a non-authenticated computer. A non-authenticated computer is any computer that is not your primary computer, an elected authenticated computer or a computer that automatically deletes cookies.
`<p>This is a test</p>`*

...and I want to remove `<p>This is a test</p>` from the field, what statement would be best?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this programatically? Do you need to automate this?  Or are you looking for a one-off solution?

Comment: I'm just wondering if I can do this in SQL.  This is just a one-off solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally would recommend the REPLACE string function:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

```
UPDATE table SET fieldname = REPLACE(fieldname, '<p>This is a test</p>', '');
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't seem to remove the string from the field.

Comment: I take that back, just had to reload the table.  Thanks!